# Set CHMOD 777 for all folder and subfolder in catalog/view/theme/machiko/skins! (Windows)

Tags: windows, permissions, themes, opencart-3

I'm newbie in opencart and I'm trying to install a theme in opencart 3.0.3.2 I was following their instructions and there is a step to add skin. Whenever I try to add skin it gives me error :

> You need to set CHMOD 777 for all folder and subfolder in catalog/view/theme/machiko/skins!

I've also tried to setup opencart on server using cPanel and get the same error (In cPanel I've given 0777 permissions to all required folders). Can anyone please help me Figure out where is the problem and how to solve it.
I've provided a screenshot where I'm getting error.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't have permission for install new theme at this folder, with this command you set the permission for read, write and execute the all files in the current directory

`chmod 777 -R ./`
-R will recurse through the whole file system

Comment: Apparently it'll be `chmod -R 777 ./` for MacOS. Just in case.